# A graph has 5 vertices of degree 4 and 2 vertices of degree 2. How many edges does it have?

Tags: graph-theory

We know for any graph G, the sum of the degrees of its vertices is twice its number of edges.

In this case, the sum of degrees is: 5(4)+2(2)=20+4=24

According to our fact, 24=2 times number of edges.

Therefore, number of edges=24/2= 12.

Does this seem correct? Is there a better, more detailed way of explaining this?

Comment: Yes, it's all correct and it's the most intuitive way of explaining this.